# Orbeon : Use of Rest API with Oracle persistence layer

Tags: javascript, oracle, orbeon

Can you help us pls with a problem concerning Orbeon

We have an external web application that includes in its pages Xforms created with Orbeon Form Builder and published in Form Runner.
We configured the Oracle persistence layer for persisting form data.
Till now all the environment is ok.
Now we have data from the external web app that we want to send to a new form data and save it in the Oracle database.
So, we think of using the Rest API provided by Orbeon to create the data as explained here : [persistence API](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api) by making ajax calls to the link to form data.
But, we dont know how to achieve this exactly (meaning how to build the ajax call, the request body, ...etc.). So can you please tell us if it's a good solution and how to do?

We also tried this (an ajax call to post to the URL a part of the instance):

```
var buffer = "<form>" +
                "<attachment>" +
                "<attachment_one filename=" + info.attachment.name + " mediatype=" + info.attachment.contentType
            + " size=" + info.attachment.size + " >" + info.attachment.bytes + "</attachment_one>" +
                "</attachment>" +
                "</form>";
        var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
        xmlDoc.load(buffer);
        $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: urlToXml, // "/crud/[APPLICATION_NAME]/[FORM_NAME]/data/[FORM_DATA_ID]/data.xml"
            processData: false,
            data: xmlDoc,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(msg) {
                alert ("xml data sent successfully");
            }
        });
```

But the response returns an invalid XML doc.

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

I would discourage you from doing this from the web browser, as this would mean that you need to make your persistence API accessible from the Internet. As a consequence, any user could access any data in your database including updating and deleting data.

If security is not a concern to you, or if you're running this JavaScript from the server with something like Node.js, then you "just" need to do a `PUT` as the Form Runner would. To know know exactly what the XML you need to send should look like, I would do the operation in Form Runner and look at what data is sent to the persistence layer with an HTTP analyzer such as [HTTP Scoop](http://tuffcode.com/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: I tried what you said by inspecting FormRunner save button with firebug but i only see a post to : /orbeon/xforms-server which is not like explained for the persistence API

Comment: @user1173005 You are looking at the requests going from the browser to the server. Instead you want to look at the requests from the server to the server, that are done over HTTP. For this, you obviously can't use a browser plugin; you'll need to use a software like HTTP Scoop or Wireshark (see the links in my response).